# Ubuntu 14.04: Problem performing software upgrades (and installing any further packages)

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg

I've just booted up an old Toshiba A100 laptop running 14.04, however I cannot complete the software updates or install any further packages.  The error message is:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
reading files list for package 'linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic': Input/output error
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I've googled the error message, but no luck...  I'm a bit of an Ubuntu terminal newbie, so any suggestions welcomed...

Comment: This could be anything, but is likely a **hardware fault** with the drive (or controller). Do some basic diagnostics, and/or backup (any data/settings) and re-install Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for this @david6, any ideas on what commands would be good to start with for diagnosing hardware faults?